# Homogeneous cores and heterogeneous cores

Tags: cpu, multi-core, multi-processor

I am currently reading up on multi-core architecture for CPUs. However, I am having difficulties understand the meaning of "using one core design repeated consistently" which describes homogeneous cores. While heterogeneous cores "uses a mixture of cores". I do not understand what is really meant by "mixture of cores". Could someone please explain what is meant by "mixture of cores"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homogeneous cores are identical, they can perform exactly the same tasks and have exactly the same capabilities available. The cores are *functionally* identical.

Heterogeneous cores are *not* identical. The can differ in capabilities, speed, may lack certain features or otherwise perform a task differently.

A current modern PC processor has homogeneous cores, there is no difference in power used when a task is performed on one core rather than another. A task can expect to be completed in exactly the same time irrespective of which core it gets scheduled on.

Modern high-end phones tend to have heterogeneous cores.  Many mix Arm A53 "low power" cores and A57 "high performance" cores.  The A57s have longer pipelines and perform significantly better, but have worse power dissipation.  The A53 cores on the other hand are highly power efficient and usually are not as fast as their larger cousins, but they can actually perform the same tasks.  They execute the same code, but *how* that code is executed is different.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to understand this is e.g. to compare an `Intel Xeon E5-2660` and a `Mediatek MT6750`.

- Both have 8 Cores
- The Xeon has 8 (almost) identical cores
- The Mediatek has 4 low power (consumption and performance) and 4 higher power cores

While for the server-targeted Xeon the core count is a means of scaling, for the smartphone-targeted Mediatek the power consumption (and its inverse, the battery life) is tantamount: When only very little work is to do, the tiny low-power cores are good enough and the more powerfull ones are actually powered off to conserver battery.

Answer (score 0):

- Homogeneous: "using one design repeatedly"
- Heterogeneous: "using multiple different designs" (a 'mixture' of different designs)

From [Wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogeneous_computing):

> Heterogeneous computing refers to systems that use more than one kind of processor or cores.